# Tensorial Package Installation

Tags: packages, installation

I tried to install the [Tensorial5](http://www.tensorial.online/) package according to its developers' instructions, however, I was unable to call the package using `Needs`.

Does anyone have any experience installing this package?

I appreciate any help or suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip in `$UserBaseDirectory` or preferably elsewhere. I could not get it to work with the entire directory structure anyways. There are folders for Windows and Mac files in there. Use the appropriate one.

Keep descending down the folder structure. Under `English` there will be a Tensorial5 folder. Copy and bring it up to `Application` folder as shown in the image. Rename or delete the unzipped folder or move it elsewhere. Then run `Get` command as shown. It tries to download/find? a paclet and fails (Never mind). Then run `Needs` command. It will succeed.

I am sure there is a better way, but this package is from 2006 so perhaps that is the reason a simple unzip and invoking `<<` wouldn't work on the default directory structure.

When you find a better solution, please post your own answer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Syed! It works! :)

Comment: Ok, if I find a better solution, I won't hesitate to post it here.